# Delete Rows Older Than 3 months (EPOCH TIME)

Tags: row, delete-row, epoch

I have a table called email_list_subscriber_events that collects data such as which email campaigns were opened, etc. I only want to keep this information for the last three months or 90 days. Any information later than 90 days should be deleted.

I have tried many different commands but I don't know how to do it because the column `lastupdate` is the time in EPOCH.

I have done a lot of googling and everything I have found is like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE lastupdate(year, 2, CreateDate) < getdate()
```

Which seems to be dealing with a regular date & time. How would I delete this data, older than 90 days, from the table. The time is in the column `lastupdate` and is in Epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the unix timestamp when you store the data in the table, then, every so often you can delete data where the timestamp is less than what the timestamp was 90 days ago. To work that out, simply find out that there are 7776000 seconds in 90 days, so delete anything where the timestamp is < current_time-7776000.